# Does Locker Service work on Salesforce1 App and mobile browser

Tags: locker-service

Dear Salesforce Developer,

I've tested locker services on SF1 App and mobile browser. It doesn't work.
So Locker service isn't supported on SF1 App and mobile browser

Sample Code:

Test.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <div >
        <ui:outputText aura:id="hid_redirectLbl" value="abcd"/>
    </div>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doPreInit}" /> 

</aura:component>
```

TestController.js

```
({
    doPreInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert(component.find("hid_redirectLbl").get('v.value'));
    }

})
```

Bug:

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] TypeError: A WeakMap cannot have a non-object key\
throws at https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:455:241\
https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:154:27\
Vy@https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:154:301\
Za@https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:518:88\
a@https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:578:394\
https://sdp-dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/S8McHzEoUFAXrY8BUJ5Khw/aura_prod.js:578:765}
```

Updated: 
The error will be occurred on iOs version 8.1.3

The higher iOs version is OK

Regards,

Comment: @user36439 At which exact point you found its not working ?

Comment: @user3643, your example works here in S1. The type of error you are reporting worth an investigation, and should not be mobile-specific. Could you provide more information?

Comment: @user36439: did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

LS is certainly intended to work in all supported browsers which includes those you listed. Your repro case also looks legitimate. There is no open or known issue on this error message currently though. Do you have a salesforce support case open on this yet?